# How to turn text into DOM elements using Clojurescript? (And Om?)

Tags: clojurescript, om

In a ClojureScript/Om app, I have a DOM and a string of HTML.

How can I translate that string of HTML into elements I can insert into the DOM?

I've started down the path of parsing the HTML with hickory, planning to then process the hickory data to create DOM elements, but I think there must be a simpler way I'm overlooking.

(I don't need to validate the HTML, I can assume it's safe and valid enough.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to parse the HTML string. It's unnecessary overhead. React/Om supports something like DOM's `innerHTML` property. Just set the prop this way:

```
(om.dom/div #js {:dangerouslySetInnerHTML #js {:__html "<b>Bold!</b>"}} nil)
```

If you work with plain DOM without Om, set the `innerHTML` property like:

```
(let [div (. js/document getElementById "elId")]
     (set! (. div -innerHTML) "<b>Bold!</b>"))
```

Comment: Much better than my answer.

Comment: With Sablono, it would be [:div {:dangerouslySetInnerHTML {:__html "<b>Bold!</b>"}}]

Answer (score 3):

Aleš Roubíček answer is much better. I'll leave this un case it helps somebody.

Hickory offers a `as-hiccup` function. [Hiccup](https://github.com/weavejester/hiccup) uses Clojure data structures to represent HTML. You could feed those data structures to Clojurescript libraries that follow the same conventions:

- [Hiccups](https://github.com/teropa/hiccups) to generate regular DOM elements.
- [Sablono](https://github.com/r0man/sablono) to generate React DOM elements and use with Om.

You could also use [Kioo](https://github.com/ckirkendall/kioo)/[Enfocus](https://github.com/ckirkendall/enfocus) and instead of passing a file path, pass the string directly. This would be more direct and instead of using two libraries (Hickory + Sablono) you would use only one. The caveat is that Kioo and Enfocus follow the [Enlive](https://github.com/cgrand/enlive) style of templating (which is great but has a learning curve) and the docs are focused on file paths and not strings (even though it is possible to pass strings).